# How can I response a type I should use in the lambda which is the resolver of a subscription in Appsync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I am building grpahql on Appsync and use websocket as subscription communication channel. Below is the scheme:

```
type Subscription {
    addedPost: Post
    @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["addPost"])
    updatedPost: Post
    @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["updatePost"])
    deletedPost: Post
    @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["deletePost"])
}
```

and I will attach lambda as the resolver for these subscription fields. In the schema, each subscription fields returns `Post` as response type. In my lambda resolver, what should I return? In the lambda, it doesn't know anything about `Post` because `Post` is used in the `mutation`. I don't understand what I should return in the subscription resolver lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the AppSync docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-data.html) you will find the following:

> Subscriptions are triggered from mutations and the mutation selection set is sent to subscribers.

You don't need to attach resolvers for subscriptions with AppSync. AppSync takes care of this for you. By using the @aws_subscribe directive you are associating the response of the `addPost` mutation to the the `addedPost` subscription.

You would just need to ensure, in this case, that the `addedPost` selection set is a subset of the `addPost` selection set.